# Why is splice not removing elements from my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I am creating a roulette game that displays random items from different arrays when the wheel lands on a specific category. So far everything works except when the wheel lands on a category, it selects the same random item from the correct array over and over again. I am trying to use math.random and the splice method to randomly select an item from an array, and remove that item so only new, random items from the array can be displayed after, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: `symbolZones[1]` means 2nd position `[0`]` is first position. You need to iterate thru the array.

Comment: Could you clarify by including an example of a possible correct output and an example of what you are getting and what is wrong with that output?

Comment: For example, I see [undefined,["e"],["i"],["d"],["i"],["d"],["g"],["a"],["f"]] after running the code. What is wrong with that? What do you expect to see?

Comment: In your example, you're only calling splice on each array once, so you never access one of the arrays after removing an element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rearranged the input arrays into an array of arrays (5 arrays of 9 elements = 45). I'm guessing that you want the whole thing shuffled.

```js
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

let zones = [
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
];
let zoneSize = zones.length * zones[0].length;
let symbolZones = [];

for (let i = zoneSize; i > 0; i--) {
  let deg = zones.flatMap(z => z.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * z.length), 1));
  if(deg.length > 0) {
    symbolZones.push(deg);
  }
}
log(`Original Array zones`);
log(zones);
log(`New Array symbolZones`);
log(symbolZones);
```

```css
.as-console-row-code {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}

.as-console-row::after {
  content: ''!important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the rest of the code is, but if you always get the same value over and over again it could be that you're not re-running the code that gets the values.

Try wrapping the logic for retrieving the symbolZones in a function:

```js
function getSymbolZones() {

  const symbolZones = [];

  symbolZones[1] = a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)];
  symbolZones[2] = b[Math.floor(Math.random()*b.length)];
  symbolZones[3] = c[Math.floor(Math.random()*c.length)];
  symbolZones[4] = d[Math.floor(Math.random()*d.length)];
  symbolZones[5] = e[Math.floor(Math.random()*e.length)];
  symbolZones[6] = f[Math.floor(Math.random()*f.length)];
  symbolZones[7] = g[Math.floor(Math.random()*g.length)];
  symbolZones[8] = h[Math.floor(Math.random()*h.length)];

  return symbolZones;
}
```

and then use it in the `handleWin` function.

```js
const handleWin = (actualDeg) => {
  const symbolZones = getSymbolZones();
  const winningSymbolNr = Math.ceil(actualDeg / zoneSize);
  display.innerHTML = symbolZones[winningSymbolNr];
}
```

**P.S.**
I understand that you start the array at index 1 because that's the smallest zone you can get from the operation 45 / 45.
But if I were you I'd start the index from 0 and just subtract 1 when accessing the array: `symbolZones[winningSymbolNr - 1]`.
This way you don't get weird bugs when trying to loop through an array that has an empty first index.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using `array`, I would suggest you use `object` and a for loop to make the code easier to execute. This code should work:

```js
let deg = 0;
// The 360 degree wheel has 8 zones, so each zone is 45 degrees
let zoneSize = 45;
let symbol = {
  a: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
  b: ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
  c: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
  d: ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
  e: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
  f: ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
  g: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
  h: ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
}

// zones for each 8 categories
let ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(symbol).length)
console.log(Object.values(symbol)[ran])
//Random select a zone from above 8 
let selectedzone = Object.values(symbol)[ran]
//Random select an item from selected zone
let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * selectedzone.length)
let symbolZones = selectedzone[index]
console.log(symbolZones)
const handleWin = (actualDeg) => {
  const winningSymbolNr = Math.ceil(actualDeg / zoneSize);
  display.innerHTML = symbolZones[winningSymbolNr];
}
```

Comment: When i tried this it still returned the same element multiple times, however now it does not recognize the different categories, and showed questions from other arrays

Comment: @trynacode, just a little confused by what you describe. What does it mean it doesn't recoginze the different categories? Could you describe it more specificially? What I did now is to get a random number from every `array` (a-h) and push to ` symbolZones`, is that what you want to did?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Basically I have 8 different categories of numbers which are separated into 8 different arrays. My problem is that I want to get a random number from the zone that is selected - i.e. if zone 1 is selected, i would get a random number from zone a. That worked with my code before, but then when that same zone is selected it shows me the previous number, instead of a new shuffled number

Comment: @trynacode, I just updated the code. Now it will first random select 1 zone from 8 zones and random select an item from the selected zone.  The problem that it may have duplicate is because you have several zones with same value. I could updated the code to prevent duplicate from the previous one, do you need it, but then it won't considered random?

Comment: @trynacode, if you find my answer helpful, please accept it and I will be appreciated for that:)